# Image processing approach capturing the contours and calculating the area

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am processing images with pyhton using opencv libraries. Objects will come to a fixed camera angle and these objects will be indented. Objects will appear at different heights while coming to a fixed viewing angle. My goal is to capture the contours of this recessed structure and measure the distances of its recesses and protrusions. And after capturing the remaining rectangular area inside, calculating its area
[image]
[image]
[image]
what is the the approach functions i need to follow for this?

I managed to extract the contours of the image, but I have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: Please post a [mre] including a sample input image.